# Check button State on ionic

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get the Toggle state as soon as i click on a button.

The problem is i always get true, even if my toggle is false.

I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrong with the DOM

Exemple.html

This is my toggle-button

```
 <ion-toggle class="toggle-small" toggle-class="toggle-calm" id="toggle"  [disabled]="value < 21"  (ionChange)="addChild(ioToggle.checked)"  #ioToggle ></ion-toggle>
```

And this is the exemple.ts

```
let toggle = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('toggle'));
    console.log(toggle) // see the image 
    if (toggle == true){
      console.log('this toggle is true')
     }
    else if (toggle == false){
      console.log('this one is false')
     }
```

this is what i get for console.log(toggle)

[image]

I'm pretty sure i need to access to the aria-checked. ( if i disable the toggle aria-checked change to false) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it

```
 let toggle = (<HTMLInputElement> document.getElementById('undefined')).getAttribute('aria-checked');
```

There is another atribute on the toggle one. ( *ionic_thing*)